# OAuth Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, compiler-errors

So I've recently gotten back into programming after a short hiatus and I'm looking to build an app for use in my business.

What I am trying to do is call upon an [API (Etsy's)](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation). The problem is that this API uses OAuth to access it and I have no idea how OAuth works. I've tried reading up on it but to no avail.

I found [this article](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49) that I thought seemed pretty simple but I'm stuck.

It tells me to use [this wrapper](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65377#1710422) for OAuth Authentication and I have the files (OAuth.cs and Tracing.cs) added in my project but it spits a few errors that I don't understand as I'm pretty much a self taught programmer.

Here is the code I have.

```
public static void getOAuthKey()
    {

        string ConsumerKey = "fakekey";
        string ConsumerSecret = "fakesecret";
        OAuth["consumer_key"] = ConsumerKey;
        OAuth["consumer_secret"] = ConsumerSecret;
        OAuthResponse = requestToken =
            OAuth.AcquireRequestToken("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=transactions_r", "POST");
    }
```

And it spits back the following errors.

- 'OAuth' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'variable'
- 'OAuth' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'variable'
- The name 'OAuthResponse' does not exist in the current context
- The name 'requestToken' does not exist in the current context
- The type or namespace name 'AcqureiRequestToken' does not exist in the namespace 'OAuth' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Can anyone help me to alleviate these errors and move past this roadblock? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found some OAuth libraries from `nuget`. Maybe you need to install those `OAuth` library from `nuget`.

Comment: I think you should be using Manager class from http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65377 not OAuth namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you have added reference to TwitPic project from the wrapper to your project.

```
public static void getOAuthKey()
            {
                string ConsumerKey = "fakekey";
                string ConsumerSecret = "fakesecret";
                Manager m = new Manager();
                m["consumer_key"] = ConsumerKey;
                m["consumer_secret"] = ConsumerSecret;
                OAuthResponse requestToken =
                    m.AcquireRequestToken(@"https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=transactions_r", "POST");
            }
```